# Get 2 values from nested arrays

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an array which has 2 arrays within. I want to echo 2 values from the nested arrays.

The value keys are:

[documentroot]

[domain]

Here is my array:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array (
            [all_aliases_valid] => 
            [usecanonicalname] => Off
            [owner] => root
            [documentroot] => /home/oneclickinstalle/public_html/test
            [group] => oneclickinstalle
            [can_https_redirect] => 
            [ip] => 172.105.97.228
            [hascgi] => 1
            [type] => sub_domain
            [homedir] => /home/oneclickinstalle
            [ipv6] => 
            [no_cache_update] => 0
            [servername] => test.oneclickinstaller.io
            [serveradmin] => webmaster@test.oneclickinstaller.io
            [phpopenbasedirprotect] => 1
            [serveralias] => www.test.oneclickinstaller.io
            [userdirprotect] => 
            [user] => oneclickinstalle
            [domain] => test.oneclickinstaller.io
            [is_https_redirecting] => 
            [status] => not redirected
        )

    [1] => Array (
            [domain] => demo.oneclickinstaller.io
            [user] => oneclickinstalle
            [is_https_redirecting] => 
            [status] => not redirected
            [userdirprotect] => 
            [serveralias] => www.demo.oneclickinstaller.io
            [serveradmin] => webmaster@demo.oneclickinstaller.io
            [phpopenbasedirprotect] => 1
            [servername] => demo.oneclickinstaller.io
            [ipv6] => 
            [no_cache_update] => 0
            [hascgi] => 1
            [homedir] => /home/oneclickinstalle
            [type] => sub_domain
            [ip] => 172.105.97.228
            [group] => oneclickinstalle
            [can_https_redirect] => 
            [documentroot] => /home/oneclickinstalle/public_html/demo
            [owner] => root
            [all_aliases_valid] => 
            [usecanonicalname] => Off
        )

)
```

I managed to be able to get it working but just for the domain name, I'm not able to get the [documentroot] value at the same time.

Here is my loop,

```
foreach ( $wp_sub_domains_array as $array => $sub_domain ) {
  foreach( $sub_domain as $key => $sub_domain_name ) {
    if( $key == "domain" ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $sub_domain_name . "'>" . $sub_domain_name . "</option>";
     }
  }
}
```

I want to echo the [documentroot] value next to the domain name, like this,

```
foreach ( $wp_sub_domains_array as $array => $sub_domain ) {
  foreach( $sub_domain as $key => $sub_domain_name ) {
    if( $key == "domain" ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $sub_domain_name . "|" . $sub_domain_documentroot . "'>" . $sub_domain_name . "</option>";
     }
  }
}
```

I'm a newbie and obviously doing something wrong or there's something fundamental I'm not understanding. Any insight would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one loop to loop through all subdomain information array, then you can access the information directly from it.

```
foreach ( $wp_sub_domains_array as $array => $sub_domain ) {
   echo "<option value='" . $sub_domain['domain'] . "|" . $sub_domain['documentroot'] . "'>" . $sub_domain['domain'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds. That's got to be a new record margin! :)

Comment: @catcon wow, that was quick! Worked perfectly. Thanks for that. Was struggling with that all afternoon. Still got some learning to do.